# How to add a asterisk red mark for textview/edittext in android for making it as a mandatory field?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have fields such as email, contact, address and city name in my android app.. I want to make that fields as mandatory to be filled by the user and for the same.. I need a asterisk red mark for such fields.. How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To insert asterisk mark with read color -

Add this to your mainactivity.xml file -

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:text="@string/name1" />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="171dp"
        android:layout_height="132dp"
        android:text="@string/name2" />
```

Add this to your strings.xml under resources tag -

```
<string name="name1">Mandatory field 1<font color='#FF0000'>*</font></string>
<string name="name2">Mandatory field 2<font color='#FF0000'>*</font></string>
```

The color of asterisk will not display in android studio but it will display in mobile device. i have added 2 examples. likewise you can add many textviews..
Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey thanks saurabh for the solution.. But I already applied this logic and it's working fine.. My question is how to add asterisk red mark for the fields.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This code will set the icon asterisk to the left

```
EditText editText= (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.myTxtView);
//just find an icon asterisk and put it to drawable folder
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks @cyrille con morales for the solution

Comment: This was so helpful. for anyone who wants to add some padding from view like me, this function does what you want `editText.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add asterisk programmatically, then follow instructions from @Cyrille Con Morales , in xml if you want to add asterisk to the right of your text, do this:

```
 <TextView
    .... 
      android:drawableRight = "@drawable/redAsterisk"
  />
```

if to the left(hebrew and other right to left alphabets), then this:

```
 <TextView
    .... 
      android:drawableLeft = "@drawable/redAsterisk"
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create custom TextView. check below code which I have used.

Create custom TextView java class.

```
public class AsteriskTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    String colored = "*";
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    public AsteriskTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        updateText();
    }

    public AsteriskTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        updateText();

    }

    public AsteriskTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        updateText();
    }

    public void updateText() {
        try {
            builder.append(getText());  //get string
            builder.append(" "); // add space between text and start
            int start = builder.length();
            builder.append(colored);
            int end = builder.length();
            builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            setText(builder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Now use in XML layout check out below example.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <com.expertbrains.widgets.AsteriskTextView              
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:paddingLeft="10dp"
         android:paddingRight="10dp"
         android:text="@string/company" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put an `ImageView` and align it right of the EditText. You can then put a red * image in the `ImageView` and scale it to `fit-xy`. Finally in your Activity class, check if the EditText is empty or not before performing your next task.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple java class **AestrickSpanAdjuster**

```
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.style.MetricAffectingSpan;

public class AestrickSpanAdjuster extends MetricAffectingSpan {
    double ratio = 0.5;

    public AestrickSpanAdjuster(double ratio) {
        this.ratio = ratio;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint paint) {
        paint.baselineShift += (int) (paint.ascent() * ratio);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
        paint.baselineShift += (int) (paint.ascent() * ratio);
    }
}
```

Make another class named **AestrickUtils**

```
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AestrickUtils {

    public static void setAsterick(EditText edittext, String hint, String aestringWithSpace)
    {
        SpannableString mString = new SpannableString(hint+aestringWithSpace);
        if(mString.length() > 0) {
            mString.setSpan(new AestrickSpanAdjuster(0.2), mString.length() - 1,
                    mString.length(), SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        /*edittext.append("\n");
        edittext.append(mString);*/
        edittext.setHint(mString);
    }

    /**
     * This function will apply the a colorful mandatory field aestrick with different type of views mentioned and set as hint or text accordingly 
     * @param view View to be modified
     * @param hint Text with black
     * @param aestrickWithSpace text with Custom color
     * @param isText weather to set text or hint with these values
     * @param colorCode color needed for aestrickWithSpace
     */
    public static void setTextViewAsterick(View view, String hint, String aestrickWithSpace, boolean isText, int colorCode)
    {
        SpannableString mString = new SpannableString(hint+aestrickWithSpace);
        if(mString.length() > 0) {
            mString.setSpan(new AestrickSpanAdjuster(0.2), mString.length() - 1,
                    mString.length(), SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            mString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colorCode), mString.length() - 1, mString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        }
        /*txtView.append("\n");
        txtView.append(mString);*/
    //  txtView.setHint(mString);
        if (view instanceof TextView)
        {
            if (isText)
                ((TextView)view).setText(mString);
            else
            ((TextView)view).setHint(mString);
        }
        else if (view instanceof EditText)
        {
            if (isText)
                ((EditText)view).setText(mString);
            else
            ((EditText)view).setHint(mString);
        }
        else if (view instanceof CheckBox)
        {
            if (isText)
                ((CheckBox)view).setText(mString);
            else
                ((CheckBox)view).setHint(mString);
        }
    }
}
```

**Now you can do the following in ou Activity or Fragment class:**

```
AestrickUtils.setTextViewAsterick(findViewById(R.id.txtLable), getString(R.string.txt_hint), " *",
                true, getResources().getColor(R.color.asterisk_red_color));
```